# Linker 2019 error while compiling sqlite example code with cl.exe

Tags: c

I know this is some kind of linking error, and is likely due to me missing some kind of compiler option.  So please let me know what it is I'm doing wrong.

My code comes from the sample program @ http://www.sqlite.org/quickstart.html

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sqlite3.h>

static int callback(void *NotUsed, int argc, char **argv, char **azColName){
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<argc; i++){
        printf("%s = %s\n", azColName[i], argv[i] ? argv[i] : "NULL");
        }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
    }

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    sqlite3 *db;
    char *zErrMsg = 0;
    int rc;
    if( argc!=3 ){
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s DATABASE SQL-STATEMENT\n", argv[0]);
        return(1);
        }
    rc = sqlite3_open(argv[1], &db);
    if( rc ){
        fprintf(stderr, "Can't open database: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
        sqlite3_close(db);
        return(1);
        }
    rc = sqlite3_exec(db, argv[2], callback, 0, &zErrMsg);
    if( rc!=SQLITE_OK ){
        fprintf(stderr, "SQL error: %s\n", zErrMsg);
        sqlite3_free(zErrMsg);
        }
    sqlite3_close(db);
    return 0;
    }
```

I am using the "Developer Command Prompt" in Windows with the following command to compile: (the SQLite header file is in %USERPROFILE%\lib)

```
cl /I%USERPROFILE%\lib helloworld.c
```

and I get the following error message:

```
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.00.23918 for x86
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

helloworld.c
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 14.00.23918.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

/out:helloworld.exe
helloworld.obj
helloworld.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _sqlite3_close referenced in function _main
helloworld.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _sqlite3_exec referenced in function _main
helloworld.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _sqlite3_free referenced in function _main
helloworld.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _sqlite3_open referenced in function _main
helloworld.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _sqlite3_errmsg referenced in function _main
helloworld.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 5 unresolved externals
```

Comment: You need to link your code against the sqlite library (with, I assume, the /L option - though I haven't used Windows in over a decade, so that could be wrong).

Comment: There is no library in your command line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the sqlite library file on the command line, like this:

```
cl /I%USERPROFILE%\lib helloworld.c sqlite3.lib
```

EDIT: It appears they provide a .def file in their precompiled binaries, and no .lib. To create the .lib:

```
lib /def:sqlite3.def /OUT:sqlite3.lib
```

Comment: I used "%USERPROFILE%\lib\sqlite3.lib".